# Sharepoint 2013: How to open in new window a particular blog post

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using the default "blog site" template in SharePoint, my question is "how to open in new window a particular blog post?"

What happens is, although I am pointing to the particular URL,

e.g: 
http://mysite/newsandevents/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=1
http://mysite/newsandevents/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=2

This will still open the full blog roll hence we cannot link from the homepage a particular news because the purpose is defeated.

If this was ever answer before, I would really appreciate if you can direct me to the resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Script Editor Web Part and use the jQuery script below to re-write blog title links to be opened in new window.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ms-accentText').click(function () {
    $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
    });
});
</script>
```

[image]

Here is proof of concept:  https://jsfiddle.net/em2kk55o/

Comment: hi Falak, thanks for your reply, question though, should I create a .js script and reference it to the content editor?

Comment: If you want to keep it in version control then better create a .js file. http://sympmarc.com/2011/05/03/adding-jquery-to-a-sharepoint-page-step-one-always/

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with SharePoint or the issue is with me but this is not working for me. :( Is there any other way?

Comment: Can you add a script editor or content editor web part on the landing page?

Comment: Yes, I can do that. Tried adding the script as per your advise using "script editor" but it just wont work as per expectation.

Comment: Could you post the script used in script editor web part?

Comment: I inserted a script editor and below is the content: `code` <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
  $('.ms-accentText').click(function () {
    $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
 });
</script>  `code`

Comment: Update your original question with code

Comment: updated my reply, I cannot format it, but basically, I just inputted your suggested script with java switch.

Comment: hi falak, can you advise what I am doing wrong? Forgive me being vague, this is the first time I work with SharePoint. thanks.

Comment: Marian, I have updated my post with updated script and screenshot. Let me know if you still have any confusion =). Happy SharePointing!